# Make target specific variables

Tags: makefile

I am writing small makefile, and I have a problem with target specific variables, I have this piece of code:

```
FILE_SOURCE := pliki.c wczytaj_plik.c wypisz_plik.c
CONSOLE_SOURCE := wczytaj_konsola.c wypisz_konsola.c
OTHER_SOURCE := suma.c roznica.c iloczyn.c macierz.c
HEADERS := suma.h roznica.h iloczyn.h wypisz.h wczytaj.h macierz.h
DEFINE_OPT = 
NAME=macierze
FILE_OBJECTS := $(FILE_SOURCE:.c=.o)
CONSOLE_OBJECTS := $(CONSOLE_SOURCE:.c=.o)
OTHER_OBJECTS := $(OTHER_SOURCE:.c=.o)
finput: HEADERS+=pliki.h
finput: DEFINE_OPT+=-D WEWY_PLIKI
finput: OTHER_OBJECTS+=$(FILE_OBJECTS)

finput cinput: debug $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OTHER_OBJECTS) main.o
    @echo $^
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $^  

debug:
    @echo $(OTHER_OBJECTS)
```

this is a piece that is relevant, when I invoke

```
make finput
```

in target debug I get all the .o files but

```
@echo $^
```

only produces

```
suma.o roznica.o iloczyn.o macierz.o main.o
```

so it is like FILE_OBJECTS were not added, but in gnu make manual:

```
There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a   target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this   target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable  with their own target-specific variable value).
```

So it is a bit weird that $(OTHER_OBJECTS) in $(NAME) don't include $(FILE_OBJECTS), how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look a couple lines up in the same section of the GNU make manual you quoted from, you will find the following.

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target's recipe

This means the target specific value of `OTHER_OBJECTS` is not available in the prerequisites. (I haven't tried, but perhaps you can use the same workaround as with automatic variables, namely secondary expansion.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for spelling it out for me, I didn't noticed this detail.